# Trying to understand Control.BeginInvoke code over at MSDN

Tags: vb.net, begininvoke

I am referring to this [document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx) on MSDN. I understand what ".BeginInvoke" does, however looking at the example code on the document

```
Delegate Sub MyDelegate(myControl As Label, myArg2 As String)

Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim myArray(1) As Object

   myArray(0) = New Label()
   myArray(1) = "Enter a Value"
   myTextBox.BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf DelegateMethod), myArray)
End Sub 'Button_Click

Public Sub DelegateMethod(myControl As Label, myCaption As String)
   myControl.Location = New Point(16, 16)
   myControl.Size = New Size(80, 25)
   myControl.Text = myCaption
   Me.Controls.Add(myControl)
End Sub 'DelegateMethod
```

The delegate myDelegate (and the DelegateMethod) accepts a control and a string, but, at the .BeginInvoke, a Label control is passed and an array...

```
myTextBox.BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf DelegateMethod), myArray)
```

and in the "DelegateMethod" there is

```
 myControl.Text = myCaption
```

Shouldn't a string be passed instead of the array? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BeginInvoke can accept two parameters.  One is a delegate, in this case AddressOf DelegateMethod.

The other parameter is an array of parameters.  DelegateMethod accepts two parameters: a label and a string.  In order to pass these using begininvoke, an array of objects with two members is passed in to beinginvoke to match the parameters of the method: a label and a string.

So both the label and the string are passed in using this array

Comment: Then shouldn't it be  myTextBox.BeginInvoke(New MyDelegate(AddressOf DelegateMethod), myArray(1))...?

Comment: No for a couple reasons.  First is that myArray(1) is an object not an array and wouldn't match the sub definition.  The second is that if you just created an array with the string then DelegateMethod would not receive the label.  The label is passed in with the array which I think may be the source of your confusion.  "The delegate myDelegate (and the DelegateMethod) accepts a control and a string, but, at the .BeginInvoke, a Label control is passed and an array..." is not true.  A delegate and an array is passed in

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.  The framework casts the parameters appropriately from the object array on your behalf.